# How create a list

Tags: android, android-listview

who knows the name of this list 
or what is the code to create such a list
I want create a conversion calculator for basic math

[image: Lista]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely looking for a Spinner

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

Use **PopupWindow** and inflate **listview** using **custom adaptor**.

You can find PopupWindow Example in this link :
http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-popupwindow-example-in-listview.html